# Linux script to move files from muilple directories

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am trying to create a script to move files once they are placed in a directory into sub directory
Example
Files placed in `/home/userA/directory1` get moved into `/home/userA/directory1/directory2`

I have to repeat this for all the `users` under `/home` and I have to skip the user if the `directory2` does not exist.

My Script so far

```
#!/bin/bash

directory="/home/*/directory1"
directory2="/home/*/directory1/directory2/."

if [ $(ls -1A $directory | wc -l) -gt 0 ] ;
then
find $directory -type f -exec rsync --remove-source-files {} $directory2  \; &>/dev/null ;
fi
```

The issue I have with the script above is that it moves all the files into one of the `directory2`.

Comment: Curiosity: why are you using `rsync` so many times and not a simple move command `mv {} $directory2 `? BTW the test `[  $(ls -1A $directory | wc -l) -gt 0 ]`  will be always true if the directory2 is a subdirectory of the directory1.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in the home of some of your users it exists a directory called `d1` and inside this one a subdirectory called `d2`.

I suppose you want to do something similar to

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /home/*/d1 ; do
    if [ -d "$i/d2" ]; then
     # echo  "$i/d2"
     find  "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} "$i/d2" \;
    fi
done
```

**Note:**

- If in the real name of `d1` there are some spaces you need to do some gym more and protect them with a `\` (so you can write `for i in /home/*/directory\ with\ spaces; do`).
- Try to write `echo $directory2 ; exit` in your previous script and you will understand why it behaves in a different way from what you expect. More info on [File Name Expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html#sect_03_04_08).